# Network.usePublicNetwork(); showing syntax error

Tags: stellar-core, java-sdk, network

I have just migrated to AndroidX (which may or may not be related to this issue). However, Network.usePublicNetwork(); is now showing a syntax error:

[image]

Below are my imports:

```
import org.stellar.sdk.AssetTypeNative;
import org.stellar.sdk.KeyPair;
import org.stellar.sdk.Memo;
import org.stellar.sdk.Network;
import org.stellar.sdk.PaymentOperation;
import org.stellar.sdk.Server;
import org.stellar.sdk.responses.AccountResponse;
import org.stellar.sdk.responses.SubmitTransactionResponse;
```

Answer (score 2):

I've tracked down the reason for this. The following is taken from the description for the 0.8.0 SDK release:

"Configure network at the transaction and server level rather than using a singleton to determine
which network to use globally."

For server level, we already have this in place:

```
Server server = new Server("https://horizon.stellar.org");
```

At the transaction level there is now an additional argument passed, in this case `Network.PUBLIC`

```
Transaction.Builder(sourceAccount, Network.PUBLIC)
```

You can delete `Network.usePublicNetwork();`

**NOTE:**

When building your transaction, the followng may help:

`publicKeyForSourceAccount` is the public key string for the source account, and `publicKeyForDestinationAccount` is the public key string for the destination account.

`AccountResponse sourceAccount = server.accounts().account(publicKeyForSourceAccount);`

```
org.stellar.sdk.Transaction payment = new org.stellar.sdk.Transaction.Builder(sourceAccount, Network.PUBLIC)  //Have to use fully qualified name for Transaction as Firebase already has a Transaction import.
                        .addOperation(new PaymentOperation.Builder(publicKeyForDestinationAccount, new AssetTypeNative(), amount).build())
                        .addMemo(Memo.text("Create Room"))
                        .setTimeout(TIMEOUT_INFINITE)
                        .build();
```